# how to: bspwm bspc rule for floating matplotlib figures

Tags: window-manager, matplotlib

I have recently started using bspwm and I have been blown away by the improvement in my workflow. There is however one thing that has been bothering me:

I am writing data analysis scripts in python that use matplotlib for plotting. Every time a plot is drawn, my windows get rearranged because bspwm does its tiling magic. Normally, I would define a floating=True in the configuration file, however for this I need the name of the application. Something like this:

bspc rule -a matplotlib floating=on

Can somebody tell me, how can I properly address matplotlib figures?

P.S. Could somebody create a tag for bspwm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find the `WM_CLASS` (that is the name you must put in your `bspwm rule`) of any window use `xprop`. Execute

```
$xprop |awk '/WM_CLASS/{print $4}'
```

in a terminal, then click on the window you want to find the name of (in this case your matplotlib window) and you will get it printed to the terminal-

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In general, this answers the questions, but when I click on a matplotlib plot, I get ", as output. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: I think the only possibility here is that matplotlib hasn't got a WM_CLASS. So, unless you can find in the matplotlib doc how to set one, (you'll maybe need to edit the source files) you can't set a bspc rule.

Answer (score 1):

matplotlib is getting `WM_CLASS`. 
Here you can see a matplotlib window without any rules:

[image: a matplotlib window without any rules]

and here I made it floating:

[image: floating]

You need this rule in your `$HOME/.config/bspwmrc`.

```sh
bspc rule -a matplotlib state=floating
```

Here are some examples you can copy from:
[Abdullah's BSPWM Desktop Session](https://gitlab.com/Abdullah/cfg/tree/master/bspwm/.config/bspwm).

Comment: +1 In my case I had to use "Matplotlib" instead of "matplotlib"